# How to set up routes to show additional information in the URL using namespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to set up my routes to show additional information in the URL using namespaces.

In the routes.rb file I have:

```
namespace "users" do
  resources :account
end
```

So, the URL to show an account page is:

```
http://<site_name>/users/accounts/1
```

I would like to rewrite/redirect that URL as/to

```
http://<site_name>/user/1/Test_Username
```

where "Test_username" is the username of the user. Also, I would like to redirect all URLs like

```
# "Not_real_Test_username" is a bad entered username of the user.
http://<site_name>/users/accounts/1/Not_real_Test_username
```

to the above.

---

At this time I solved part of my issuelike this:

```
  scope :module => "users" do
    match 'user/:id' => "accounts#show"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for not answering your question (@zetetic has done that well enough), but the best practice here is to stay within the RESTful-style Rails URL scheme except for rare exceptions. The way most people make pretty URLs in this way is to use a hyphen, e.g.:

```
/accounts/1-username
```

This does not require any routing changes. Simply implement:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{self.id}-#{self.username}"
  end
end
```

And handle the extra string data in your finds by calling `to_i`.

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
   def show
     @account = Account.find(params[:id].to_i)
   end
end
```

When you do `link_to 'Your Account', account_path(@account)`, Rails will automatically produce the pretty URL.

Comment: Why have I to do 'params[:id].to_i'? It will work also without that: '@account = Users::Account.find(params[:id])'.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to do this in the controller, since you need to retrieve the account to get the username:

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
if @account && @account.username
  redirect_to("/user/#{@account.id}/#{@account.username}")
  return
end
```

As to the second issue, you can capture the remaining parameter by defining it in the route:

```
get "/users/accounts/:id(/:other)" => "users/accounts#show"
```

This maps like so:

```
/users/accounts/1/something # => {:id => "1", :other => "something"}
/users/accounts/1 # => {:id => "1"}
```

And  you can simply ignore the `:other` key in the controller.